# vim how to remove encoding special signs

Tags: regex, vim, encoding, character-encoding

I have a document in vim which contains encoding-related chars I want to get rid of (e.g. replace with "").

I have a general problem in describing their origin. There are examples of how they are displayed in different editors (my desired tool to get rid of them is `vim`).

- in `vim`:

`Oś<9c>więcim` (`<9c>` is a part I would like to get rid of)

- in `Geany`:

[image]

(but copy-paste copies without this 'square' sign)

- in `LibreOffice Calc`:

[image]

Please note there are other Polish-langauage-specific signs in my text whcih are displayed correct.

**Q:** how to regex it out in vim?

Comment: Do you know the encoding? Is it an option to just reload in the correct encoding?

Comment: I tried and it did not work.

Comment: What, precisely, did you try? Using encoding properly in Vim can be tricky. First there is the 'encoding' option which must support any characters used, then there is the 'fileencoding' option which must be detected via 'fileencodings' or specified by `:e ++enc=name` when editing the file.

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I tried `:e ++enc=name` command (with encodings: utf-8 and latin1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter the `<9c>` via `:help i_CTRL-V_digit` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (on Windows, often <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> instead), followed by <kbd>X</kbd> and the hexadecimal number:

```
:%s/<C-V>x9c//g
```

Alternatively, the special `\%x9c` regular expression atom matches that value:

```
:%s/\%x9c//g
```

Alternatively, you could also just yank the character when the cursor is on it via `yl`, and then paste in the `:s` command-line via `<C-R>"`.